# Is there an easy way to sort regressors by the impact they make in Stata?

Tags: output, regression, stata

Instead of the traditional regression output, I want to get a table with two columns A and B. Column A contains a list of regressors and column B contains their impacts which equal:

```
b_hat(x) / sigma(x)
```

where b_hat(x) is the marginal effect on the dependent variable due to a 1 unit change in x, and sigma(x) is a standard deviation of x.

It would be great if the list is sorted by impact.

Comment: Transforming all your X variables to have unit standard deviation before the regression will make the actual ordering process (given how you specify the ordering should be performed) much easier. What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried exactly that right after I posted it here, and it' a pretty fast hack. However, found no way to sort the regression output table yet

Answer (score 0):

This is a blunt-force way of doing what you want. You can get the idea & use it to write some sort of custom program to do something like this on the fly. This is really rough so I will appreciate comments to make this cleaner or more robust. Right now it would be pretty sensitive to rather minor things.

```
tempfile temp
sysuse auto, clear
local set "headroom trunk length turn displacement "
foreach var of varlist `set' {
egen `var'_std=std(`var')
}

local set "headroom_std trunk_std length_std turn_std displacement_std "
reg mpg `set'
preserve
mat A=e(b)
clear
set obs 1
g name = "`set'"+"cons"
split name,p(" ")
drop name
g index=_n
reshape long name,i(index) j(num) string
save `temp'
clear
svmat A
g index=_n
reshape long A,i(index) j(num)
tostring num, replace
merge 1:1 num using `temp', nogen assert(3)

drop if name=="cons"
gsort -A
replace num=string(_n)
keep num name index
reshape wide name,i(index) j(num) string
egen ordered=concat(name1-name5),p(" ")

local set2 =ordered[1]
dis "`set'"
dis "`set2'"
restore
reg mpg `set2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach in which the variable names are entered only once. It uses the -mm_ranks- command from Ben Jann's MOREMATA package at SSC and puts the sorted result into a new Stata data set.

```
sysuse auto, clear
local lhs turn
local rhs length foreign weight

putmata a = (`rhs'), view replace
mata: st_matrix("sd",sqrt(diagonal(variance(a))))

reg  `lhs' `rhs'
matrix b = r(table)'
matrix b = b[1..rowsof(b)-1,1]

mata: c = abs(st_matrix("b"):/st_matrix("sd"))
mata: rank =  rows(c):-mm_ranks(c):+1  /* SSC package MOREMATA */
mata: st_matrix("n",(c,rank))


mat n = (b, sd, n)
mat  colnames  n = beta sd impact rank
clear
svmat n , names(col)
tempfile t1
save `t1'

clear
mat np = n'
svmat np, names(col)
keep in 1
xpose, varname clear
keep _varname
qui merge 1:1 _n using `t1'
drop _merge
sort rank
list
```